# Determine tag-sets in Tensorflow Hub saved model

Tags: tensorflow, tpu, google-coral

I'm trying to determine if [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2/1) **Tensorflow Hub** model can be converted to TFLITE format (and eventually compiled for the TPU/Coral Board), by doing something like this.

```
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("./")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

However, I need to specify the model tag-sets and this command gives no results (in both TF 1.13.1 and 2.0):

```
% saved_model_cli show --dir .
The given SavedModel contains the following tag-sets:
```

The *saved_model.pb* file is in this directory, and Netron is too unwieldy - given the size of the model it barely opens - so it's difficult to inspect. The model can be opened for inference: `detector = hub.load(module_url).signatures['default']` so perhaps I can show the model summary from the `detector` object (?).

1. Any ideas how I can determine the model structure?
2. Any insight into the practicality of converting this model to TFLITE and then compiling for the TPU would be appreciated.

Comment: Getting the same issue. May be this is version mismatch.